# multer destinations glitch

Tags: node.js, multer

When I try to set my destination directory with multer to 'myFolder/uploads', TWO directories called 'uploads' are created. One sits in the current working directory and another sits in 'myFolder/uploads'. Multer then saves the file into the uploads folder in the cwd. This kind of sounds like a potential glitch with multer.
Here's my route:

```
router.post('/upload', multer({dest: './myFolder/uploads/'}).single('resume'), function(req, res){
          //code logic in here
})
```

Comment: Could you please delete those two directories that you think it creates and try to upload again to see if it does what you are saying?

Comment: When I run node app.js in the cwd in terminal, the two directories are automatically created

Comment: Do you have a repository of the whole project or something? It is strange that's really happening because of the code you're showing. IMO the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: What's also really weird is that even if I specify the destination to ./images/, multer still creates a folder called uploads for me and attempts to upload the file there.

Comment: Are you sure you are not creating that folder manually or with another call to `multer`?

Comment: Ohh gosh this is embarrassing, it turns out I had one line of code app.use(multer({ dest: './images/'}).single('resume')) in my app.js file that I thought I had commented out. Thanks!

Comment: To avoid this kind of problems, next time it might be better to just make one call to the `multer` constructor as in all examples I have seen around (multer's Github repository, etc) so far...